# How can I get the application context in that situation?

Tags: android

I'm newbie at Android Development, I have been learning this about 4 months.

I'm trying to get my application context to use an library called picasso. I built a costume adapter to load images to my imageview.

But I'm having some issues getting the application context, I tried to use getBaseContext, getActivity(), and I created a variable to get the context, but it didn't work.

I'm building my app using fragments, my code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        final ArrayList alEvents = new ArrayList<String>();

        eventsAdapter = new costumeadapter(getActivity(), alEvents,
                R.layout.list, new String[] { ITEM_NAME, ITEM_EVENT },
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.current_event });

        lvEvents.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);

...

}
```

My costume adapter:

```
public class costumeadapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    Context context;

    public costumeadapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(fragmentActivity, data, resource, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView bg_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bg_image);


        Picasso.with(context)
                .load("http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_10.jpg")
                .into(bg_image);

        return v;

    }

}
```

Can you guys give me any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `getApplicationContext();`?

Comment: I tried, and I received this warning: The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type costumeadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `convertView.getContext()` or `v.getContext()` to get Context for passing to `Picasso.with` method as:

```
Picasso.with(convertView.getContext())
       .load("<IMAGE_URL>")
       .into(bg_image);
```

Comment: I tried to use convertView.getContext but it crashed, I changed to v.getContext and it worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RúbenDias: Right you can also use `v.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, declare:

```
final Context localContext;
```

and after:

```
 public costumeadapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(fragmentActivity, data, resource, from, to);
        this.localContext = fragmentActivity;
    }
```

in localContext variable you will have a context.

Answer (score 0):

You should have include how you have tried to get the context that is not working for you but I think this will work

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ImageView bg_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bg_image);


    context = parent.getContext();
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load("http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_10.jpg")
            .into(bg_image);

    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit Activity to fragment. At the fragment class, override onActivityCreated to get Activity which is contained fragment. Then getting context from this activity